# Turnkey software for a community website

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, blog, community, wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking for some software to run a small community website. Ideally, what I want is:

- A wiki
- Static pages of some kind, perhaps cms controlled.
- Some sort of blogging or news functionality

I've been playing with django, but it's difficult to get the results you want when on cheap shared hosting (limited control of httpd.conf)

Perhaps some sort of wiki package would provide most of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into Joomla or Drupal, they are both great CMS with a lot of plugins and big communities ready to help.

For the wiki part, you can add Mediawiki, which is the software used by wikipedia
And bridge them : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/wiki-integration

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

OpenAtrium (based on Drupal) does everything you want, and it shouldn't require any customization of httpd.conf. The only problem I've had with it is that it runs somewhat slow on shared hosting. But if you're not enabling a lot of extra modules you can probably get decent performance out of it depending on the resource usage of your shared server.

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to Lèse majesté: if you are happy with Drupal, you can see also at [Drupal Commons](http://commons.acquia.com/)

Alternatives (reasonable good) can be:

- [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) (with handwork as **a must**)
- [Dolphin](http://www.boonex.com/dolphin) (not a my game, from my POV)
- [ImpressCMS](http://impresscms.org/) (to *some extent* with selected modules-set and **initial sociality** in the core)